# Touch- creating files in the wrong directory

Tags: command-line

I would like to make 10 files in the folder: "folder".
I wrote `touch /home/piotr/Desktop/folder file{1..10}.txt` and I become 10 files in Desktop folder. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: fyi:  you've tagged Ubuntu-Touch which is the version of Ubuntu (originally by Canonical, now UBports) for Phone & tablets; it's not for computers and not related to the `touch` command - see https://ubports.com/ for details on the Ubuntu Touch OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a slash - it should be:

```
touch /home/piotr/Desktop/folder/file{1..10}.txt
```

Comment: Oh no. It couldn't have been that simple ;) Thank you!